# How can I cool my computer in a tropical environment?

Tags: cooling, temperature

I work from home in the Caribbean and don't like to run my A/C as it is very expensive and I would rather enjoy the breeze. The only problem is that temperatures are always > 80F and humidity is always > 70%. I know this is supposed to be a death sentence for a hard-working computer but I have been running fine for 2 years with no hardware failures but I don't I don't want to push my luck any longer.

What is the best way to cool my computer and reduce humidity in this environment without breaking the bank?

Comment: There are not many solutions to this problem without using more power (fans, dehumidifier, etc) which is your reason for not running your air conditioning. Maybe look into higher efficiency appliances if that is your main concern.

Comment: For your own sake, you may want to grab some dryer duct or similar to pipe the computer exhaust out a window. Without AC that should keep the ambient temperature in your home office down to manageable levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience, most computers I've owned have worked fine through dust, 90% humidity, and roughly 30 degree c temperatures. Keep the computer with plenty of space to vent, keep things dust free, and you should have no issues for 5-7 years at least (After which parts will start failing due to good old wear and tear). Humidity dosen't seem to have an affect on working components (and I've never seen a case rust).

I would recommend blowing out the heatsinks annually if dust is an issue - the main cause of death on my systems is the heatsinks getting covered in a nice coat of black dust.

Computers will happily run at temperatures that people can stand.

Comment: You know, if you use slower hard drives, the data won't fly off and collect on the heatsinks, less cleaning ;)

Comment: The place i live in is right next to one of the world's busiest roads, about a dozen lanes of expressway and regular traffic, and until recently, a railway passenger and freight station. Never bothered with 5400 drives personally, 7200 or bust ;)